# jquery timepicker time start issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, datetimepicker, timepicker

I have and timepicker in my code. code is given below.

```
   function getCurrentTime(date) {
    var hours = date.getHours(),
        minutes = date.getMinutes(),
        ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';

  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;

  return hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
}
 

    var cur_time = new Date();
            cur_time.setHours(cur_time.getHours() + 1);
            $('.pickup_time').timepicker({
                timeFormat: 'hh:mm p',
                interval: 30,
                minTime: getCurrentTime(new Date()),
                // minTime: '1',
                // maxTime: '11:30pm', 
                // startTime: '01:00',
                dynamic: false,
                dropdown: true,
                scrollbar: true           
            });
            $('.pickup_time').timepicker('setTime', cur_time);
```

Using this code i am getting dropdown like which is given below in image .what i exactly want is i want to start the time from the 2:00 when its 1:43. and if time is 1:25 i want it toi start from 01:30.

[image]

Help needed on this can any one have idea about this ???

Comment: Looks like the `minTime` property needs to be tweaked. Can you show the function `getCurrentTime()` which is used to set this property?

Comment: Hello @Moutah i have updated my question please have a look

Answer (score 0):

In order to round the current time to the next half hour, adjust your `getCurrentTime()` function as follows:

```js
function getCurrentTime(date) {
  // extract hours and minutes from given date
  var hours = date.getHours(),
    minutes = date.getMinutes();

  // round minutes to half hour or next hour
  if (minutes <= 30) {
    minutes = "30";
  } else {
    minutes = "00";
    hours = (hours + 1) % 24; // loop on 24 hours
  }

  // calc if morning or afternoon
  var ampm = hours >= 12 ? "pm" : "am";

  // adjust hour to 12h format
  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'

  return hours + ":" + minutes + " " + ampm;
}
```